# If $u_{n+1}-u_{n}= c -n$ what facts can be deduced?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose I have a sequence such that $u_{n+1} - u_n = c - n $ with $c \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Now, this clearly show that the sequence is decreasing.

If I don't know whether the sequence is bounded from under, what else can I say about the sequence?

Does the fact that $u_{n+1} - u_{n} \underset{n \infty}{\rightarrow} - \infty$ mean that $u_n \underset{n \infty}{\rightarrow} - \infty$ ?

After all, if $u_n$ is decreasing and $u_{n+1} -u_n \underset{n \infty}{\rightarrow} 0$ we could say that the sequence converges to a limit $l$, yet here the difference highly diverges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$u_1=u_0 + c - 0\\
u_2=u_1 + c-1 = u_0+2c-1\\
u_3=u_2+c-2=u_0 + 3c - (1+2)\\
u_4 = u_3+c-3 = u_0 + 4c - (1+2+3)$$

Can you see a pattern? Once you see it, it should be easy to show that $u_n\to - \infty$.

---

From $u_{n+1} - u_n\to -\infty$, you can also already conclude that the sequence is not Cauchy, therefore it is not convergent.

A little more work is needed to show that $u_n\to -\infty$, however it is possible to show it just from the fact that $u_{n+1}-u_n\to -\infty$. The easiest way is to show an **even weaker** statement of:

> If there exists some $N$ such that $u_{n+1} - u_n < -1$ for all $n>N$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=-\infty$$

Comment: @Steven Gregory Why did you delete your answer ? It was perfectly clear that the $O(n^2)$ term dominates the $O(n)$ term, whence the divergence conclusion.